# Inner join query with array in result field

Tags: sqlite

There 2 tables in my tables

1. contacts (Fields : firstname, lastname, id)
2. phone numbers (Fields : number, id, contact_id)

The result i am looking for is as below.

### Firsname     Lastname     Phone numbers

XYZ          ABC          Array of numbers

I tried inner join query but it shows me separate result for same contact_id. I tried to use group_by but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname, GROUP_CONCAT(p.number) AS numbers
FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers p
  ON c.id = p.contact_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cc96fe/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: that works great! Is it possible have phone numbers as array?

Comment: No, when you join numbers with `,` you will get string.